# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cpPortfolioTitleProvider <- cpPortfolioTitle

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I have that error above but I declared my dependencies well. Here is my controller.

```
ContentManagement.controller('addDirectorCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance','ContentAssessmentFactory','ContentProviderPortfolioService','cpPortfolioTitle', function($scope, $modalInstance, ContentAssessmentFactory,ContentProviderPortfolioService,cpPortfolioTitle){

$scope.individualDetails = cpPortfolioTitle;
$scope.hideAlert = true;

$scope.close = function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
};

$scope.editDirector = function(id, directorName){
    var titleDirector = {
        cpPortfolioItemId: id,
        name: directorName,
        job: 'director'
    };
    ContentAssessmentFactory.addDirector(titleDirector);
    $scope.hideAlert = false;
};
```

}]);

and here is my modal declaration in another controller

```
$scope.modalAddDirector = function(){
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'components/content-management/content-assessment/partial/modal/addDirector.html',
        controller: 'addDirectorCtrl',
        size: 'sm',
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
};
```

I cannot solve the error injector problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you declare cpPorfolioTitle?

Comment: Can you show `cpPortfolioTitle`? Where have you delcared it? is `cpPortfolioTitle` in a different module?